# Elastic Search Json field query with number key

Tags: javascript, json, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

How can I query elastic search based on the number key?

JSON field name
years_of_experience :

```
"{\"61\": \"10\", \"8240\": \"5\", \"8249\": \"2\", \"50\": \"0\", \"2079\": \"2\"}"
```

I want to filter years_of_experience like 50:0.

Comment: Could you give more detail? What does it mean to filter of year?of_experience. I can write to you an answer as "use painless script" :) you can get the more detailed answer but if you can give more details

Comment: I have some data in elastic search which has one JSON field named years_of_experience. like.
"{\"61\": \"10\", \"8240\": \"5\", \"8249\": \"2\", \"50\": \"0\", \"2079\": \"2\"}"

Now I want to query years_of_experience with key and value.
query years_of_experience based on 50 as the key and 0 as the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, according to your sample, you have documents like the below:

```
POST myindex/_doc
{
  "years_of_experience": {
    "50": "0",
    "61": "10",
    "2079": "2",
    "8240": "5",
    "8249": "2"
  }
}
```

So, you have an object for `years_of_experience`, and you want to do an exact match with the field name and values. You need to set all fields inside this field you want to set as a `keyword` type. First, you need to handle the mapping part of this problem. Here is a solution for this :

```
PUT myindex
{
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 1,
    "number_of_replicas": 0
  },
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic_templates": [
      {
        "strings_as_keyword": {
          "match_mapping_type": "string",
          "path_match": "years_of_experience.*",
          "mapping": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "properties": {
      "years_of_experience": {
        "type": "object"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

While creating your index for this data, you need to use a dynamic template for the `years_of_experience` object. And all the fields inside this will be `keyword` type, and you can run term queries on these fields.

So now we can create the documents after creating an index with the above settings. And you can filter the data as below :

```
GET myindex/_search
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "years_of_experience.50": "0"
    }
  }
}
```